# Rewrite rule for replacing a single character. Once

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace

I need some help with .htaccess files and mod_rewrite.

Now I've got a script for my SMS Payment provider, which executes different tasks according to what variables you parse to it.
The problem is, that the script is called like:

```
http://examp.le/path/script.php&param1=x&param2=whatever&param3=823
```

and so on.
This, as you definitely know, is wrong. The first character should be a query mark, not an ampersand. So I need to write a rewrite rule to replace the **first occurence** of the ampersand with a query mark. I've never been good at regex, or htaccess in general.

**But.** If you're answering, please explain what characters do what and how in the world does it work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(script\.php)&(param1=[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: The first line was giving me a 500, but rewrites work on my server without it (probably already set), so I removed it. I changed param1 to idt (the actual first param), but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: What is exact URL that you entered? Also can you post your complete .htaccess in your question as you may have some conflicting rules there.